# How to pass user defined table type input parameter to stored procedure in wso2 data services server(dss)?

Tags: sql, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

I am developing WSO2 dss service. My requirement is to pass user defined table parameter to Stored procedure in WSO2 DSS. I am able to pass user defined type but not user defined type table  in dss. Any small sample for passing user defined type table in data services server in wso2 is needed.
Any help will  be appreciated.

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44635865/insert-multiple-rows-in-database-with-single-database-call-from-wso2-dss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Now, WSO2 is not supporting passing user defined table parameter to stored procedure in DSS.