# Insert multiple rows in database with single database call from WSO2 DSS

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We started using WSO2 recently as an integration layer to communicate with different systems but we hit a problem while calling an existing stored procedure present in SQL server database. This stored procedure takes a user defined table type (UDTT) and single SP call can pass thousands of rows in the UDTT.
We've tried enabling batch requests but when the DSS API is tried with multiple rows, multiple database calls are being made once for each row defeating the purpose of having a UDTT as input, so we would like to know if it's really possible to pass multiple rows using a single database call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We reached out to WSO2 support and we've been informed that it's not possible as of now.

But it would be really nice to have this feature as WSO2 is used for enterprise level systems and usually the data is huge and can't be sent row by row to database, therefore increasing traffic to database server. Really wish we had this feature, now we have to search for alternatives.